# is it ok to change data in a GET request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, web

I'm adding email confirmation and when users click an email activation link, it does a get request to get the signup page and populate the signup form. However, I would like to also update my user's email_confirmed attribute to true in this action. I've heard to never change data on a get request but I'm not sure how else to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is good practice not to change data from GET requests, there are cases where you don't have a choice, and this is one them.

An HTML anchor (`<a>` tag) can only submit a GET request to your server. To use other methods (POST, PATCH, etc.) you would have to use JavaScript, but you can't rely on your recipient's email client to run that.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a good practice not to change data in GET requests. It's not enforced in the language or framework level.

What you could do is show a Confirm Email button on the GET page which makes a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where practicality trumps pedantry.  It's true that HTTP GET is supposed to be a non-modifying and idempotent action.  But sometimes it's just plain easier to GET than to POST or PUT in these cases.  It's also nice for testing, just paste the URL in your browser :)

Answer (score 0):

The page served for GET can contain a button that triggers the actual (POST) action that modifies the state.